# Trouble starting an Activity from a countDownTimer

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, countdowntimer

I have a CountDownTimer in a Broadcast receiver supposed to start an Activity.

But after several attempts I can't get the Activity to start...

Here is a code snippet of my last attempt after some reading but startActivityForResult is not recognised...

```
public class GSMCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer  {  
        public GSMCountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval)
        {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish(){        
           if (reseau   ==  false){
              Intent fIntent = new Intent();
              fIntent.setClassName("com.atelio.smart", "com.atelio.smart.AlerteGsm");
              startActivityForResult(fIntent,0);

           }
        }
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millis){     

        }                     
    }
```

I need the main class to be a broadcast receiver to listen to phone states...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use CountDownTimer in broadCastReciever.

Check the [Reciever Lifecycle Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html). Any asynchronous operation cannot be done in broadcastRecievers. Once code returns from onRecieve, Reciever object is no longer active.

So Use an AlarmManager instead.

```
AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

Intent fIntent = new Intent();
fIntent.setClassName("com.atelio.smart", "com.atelio.smart.AlerteGsm");

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, fIntent, 0);

Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
time.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
time.add(Calendar.SECOND, millisInFuture);

alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Hi Nandeesh, yes I thought about using an AlarmManager. I need advice about this. I need to check the status of the gsm connectivity, and am using PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SERVICE_STATE. Is it troubleshooting to check the network let's say every 5 sec with an AlarmManager? Or am doing this comletely wrong using the ServiceState.STATE_OUT_OF_SERVICE?

Comment: do you want to just know if there is gsm connectivity, if so you are better off using [CONNECTIVITY_ACTION intent](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html) than using PhoneStateListener. Phonestatelistener is usually to show ui updates related signal strength and other stuff

Comment: ok, but does this work for the gsm network as well? All I can read is about internet connectivity, which I don't need. I'm sorry if I express myself badly. Basically, what I need to know is if phone can receive sms, makes call etc....

Comment: Sorry, got it : connectivity.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
Thanks!